# Configuring Nginx server to python flask application

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

i am new to configuring server. And i want to configure my Amazon-EC2 instance. I configured it according to this document. http://www.soundrenalin.com/about

However when i click the url, `502 Bad Gateway` error is being encountered.
My project is located at this path: `/home/ubuntu/dsn/app`.

And the `/home/ubuntu/dsn` folder tree is:

```
app/
    app.py
    static/
    templates/
    themes/
bin/
build/
include/
lib/
local/
run.py
```

Here is my nginx config (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`):

```
server {
        listen   80; 

        root /home/ubuntu/dsn/app
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name localhost;
        location / { try_files $uri @app; }
        location @app {
             include uwsgi_params;
             uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
        }
}
```

And here is my `uwsgi.ini` file:

```
[uwsgi]
     chdir = /home/ubuntu/dsn/
     uid = www-data
     gid = www-data
     chmod-socket = 666
     socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
     module = run
     virtualenv = /home/ubuntu/dsn/
```

And the other thing is:
When i run the command `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log` result is:

```
2013/06/09 15:58:11 [error] 5321#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: <myip>, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock:", host: "54.218.14.213"
```

How can i solve this? Thanks.

Comment: in nginx config try tripple slash `uwsgi_pass unix:///unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;` . And better use manuals on official sites

Comment: What version uwsgi are you running? Run "uwsgi --version" to check.  I had a similar issue that was fixed by using the python version. Installing through apt gives you an old version, 1.1 I think. Installing via pip will get you version 1.9. Pip installs to /usr/bin/local/uwsgi, try typing "/usr/bin/local/uwsgi --version" it should return 1.9. Then just update the BINPATH line in your /etc/init/uwsgi file to "env BINPATH=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi".

Answer (score 1):

It could be one of the following things:

1. Your UWSGI socket is not located at /tmp/uwsgi.sock
2. The uwsgi or www-data user does not have permissions to create uwsgi.sock in your /tmp directory.

If you installed Uwsgi on Ubuntu 12.04, the config file should be located at:

```
/usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini
```

Here's the default socket config in that file:

```
# bind to UNIX socket at /run/uwsgi/<confnamespace>/<confname>/socket
socket = /run/uwsgi/%(deb-confnamespace)/%(deb-confname)/socket
```

You should create an app-specific config file that looks similar to mine. I can confirm it works inside a virtual environment.

```
sudo vim /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/your-app.ini
```

The contents of your-app.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
base = /home/nick/your-app.com

#location of the flask application file
file = /home/nick/your-app.com/main.py

#uwsgi varible only, does not relate to your flask application
callable = app

#uwsgi plugins
plugins = http,python

#to create within a virtual environment
home = %(base)/venv

pythonpath = %(base)
socket = /tmp/%n.sock
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
workers = 3
```

To enable, you need to symlink and restart nginx.

```
#make sure that any user to write to the /tmp directory
sudo chmod 777 /tmp
sudo ln -s /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/your-app.ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/your-app.ini
sudo service uwsgi restart
```

Answer (score -2):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/33587478/260127

You can use ubutu's upstart, and uwsgi's --emperor option to execute the python uwsgi apps easily.