# Getting "502 Bad Gateway" with nginx, uwsgi python-flask on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am following the this to deploy a *flask app(simple hello world)* on the Ubuntu 16-04. [digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Everything works fine till **Testing uWSGI Serving**. After that I followed the step as described and when I finally reach the bottom and check server IP address then I got:

```
502 Bad Gateway
```

Ok fine. I searched and checked my error log, I got this :-

```
2017/01/16 05:29:27 [crit] 20714#20714: *2 connect() to unix:/home/sajjan/project/project.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.9.xxx.xxx, server: 138.xxx.xx.xxx, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/sajjan/project/project.sock:", host: "xx.xx.xx.xx"
```

So After taking a error log , I created the file project.sock manually. again Go to server ip address and then same error **"502 Bad Gateway"**

Again checked the error log and found this

```
2017/01/16 06:07:11 [crit] 20874#20874: *1 connect() to unix:/home/sajjan/project/project.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 47.9.237.113, server: XX.XX.XX.XX, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/sajjan/project/project.sock:", host: " XX.XX.XX.XX "
```

I figured out about the permission issue and change the permission using below command

```
sudo chmod 666 project.sock
```

Now I checked the permision( using ls -l filename)

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Jan 16 05:31 project.sock
```

Now I go back to check the server's IP but found the same "502 Bad Gateway".
Again I checked the error log and found this :

```
017/01/16 06:13:31 [error] 20897#20897: *6 connect() to unix:/home/sajjan/project/project.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 47.9.237.113, server: XX.XX.XX.XX, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/sajjan/project/project.sock:", host: " XX.XX.XX.XX ", referrer: "http:// XX.XX.XX.XX /"
```

I googled for above error read a lot in last two days but nothing to seem working for me .
I have check these answers but no help [stackanswer-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011577/configuring-nginx-server-to-python-flask-application) [stackanswer-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33586013/flask-app-on-uwsgi-nginx-unix-socket-file-is-not-created-on-booting) and along with these I checked all the digital-ocean community thread but **nothing seems to work.**

I am total begineer to servers and don't know much about ubuntu. If you can help me to find out what wrong am I doing or suggest some better tutorial/ways to deploy my flask application, then I would be greatful.

These are my files

1. hello.py

   ```
   from flask import Flask
   app = Flask(__name__)

   @app.route("/")
   def hello():
       return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
   ```
2. project.ini

   ```
   [uwsgi]

   module = wsgi:app

   master = true

   processes = 5

   socket = /home/sajjan/project/project.sock

   chmod-socket = 660

   vacuum = true

   die-on-term = true
   ```
3. wsgi.py

   ```
   from hello import app

   if __name__ == "__main__":
         app.run()
   ```
4. Below is file : /etc/nginx/sites-available/project

   ```
   server {
       listen 80;
       server_name 138.197.28.107;

       location / {
           include uwsgi_params;
           uwsgi_pass unix:/home/sajjan/project/project.sock;
       }
   }
   ```

When I run the command :

```
    sudo service uwsgi restart
```

output:

```
   Failed to restart wsgi.service: Unit wsgi.service not found.
```

while output of

```
   sudo service nginx status/restart
```

then this show that nginx is running .

Help me, If anything else that you want to know then let me know.
Thanks

**EDIT :**

I have created a project.service file and its conetent is :

```
    [Unit]
    Description=uWSGI instance to serve project
    After=network.target

    [Service]
    User=sajjan
    Group=www-data
    WorkingDirectory=/home/sajjan/project
    Environment="PATH=/home/sajjan/project/venv/bin"
    ExecStart=/home/sajjan/project/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini project.ini

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I figured out I have to run below command :

```
    sudo systemctl start project
```

Output is :

```
    Warning: project.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
```

and when I run

```
     sudo systemcl reload project
```

then output :

```
    Failed to reload project.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit project.service.
    See system logs and 'systemctl status project.service' for details.
```

and when I check the "systemctl status project.service"

```
     ● project.service - uWSGI instance to serve project
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/project.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-01-16 17:49:29 UTC; 6min ago
      Main PID: 27157 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

     Jan 16 17:49:29 learningwithpython systemd[1]: Started uWSGI instance to serve project.
     Jan 16 17:49:29 learningwithpython systemd[1]: project.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
     Jan 16 17:49:29 learningwithpython systemd[1]: project.service: Unit entered failed state.
     Jan 16 17:49:29 learningwithpython systemd[1]: project.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: `Failed to restart wsgi.service: Unit wsgi.service not found. ` - sorry for captain obvious' question, but have you created `/etc/systemd/system/wsgi.service` unit file? If so, show the content.

Comment: @PiotrDawidiuk , Check the edit . Bytheway I have created a file named project.service not wsgi.service .

Comment: Message says to reload a `systemd` process, not `project`. Run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and then `sudo systemctl start project`.

Comment: @PiotrDawidiuk , Done As you said but still I am getting "502 bad gate way" with error log ......  `2017/01/17 11:31:14 [error] 28689#28689: *6 connect() to unix:/home/sajjan/project/project.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: XX.XXX.XX.XX, server: XX.XXX.XX.XX, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/home/sajjan/project/project.sock:", host: "XX.XXX.XX.XX", referrer: "http://XX.XXX.XX.XX/" `

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem using the guide. As far as I've read; 502 bad gateway is a symptom of Nginx not being able to properly connect to the uwsgi. Changing the permissions on the socket solved the issue for me.

```
sudo chmod 777 /home/sajjan/project/project.sock
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

777 is offcourse a bit excessive, but its a quick and dirty way to verify if it is in fact a problem with permissions

Comment: Thank you, this helped me identify a permissions problem. My _uwsgi_ processes were owned by a **user** called `dev`, my _nginx_ processes were owned by the `www-data` **user**, both of the users being part of the `www-data` **group**. The uwsgi Unix _socket_ was owned by `dev:www-data` (that is, **user** `dev` and **group** `www-data`), and its access mode was `660`. It didn't work, so I ended up changing my _uwsgi systemd service unit_ config and my _uwsgi site_ config so that the _uwsgi_ processes and the _socket_ were also owned by the `www-data` **user** (the _uid_ setting). Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx has no permission to write to socket. Granting appropriate mode with below command, helped me.

```
chmod 0755 /to/project
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem.

But I give the 666 permission and restart all, and it works.

I think the error log only show the problem's one possible cause. While, the `journalctl -u <yourproject>.service` command help present another reason.

My error log also tells me that he can't find the "myproject.socket". But .ini has already help us build it. Then I get this error: **myproject.service: Failed at step USER spawning ~/bin/uwsgi: No such process**

So maybe it is the permission's problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `myapp/bin/uwsgi --ini myapp.ini` to see the actual error thats preventing uwsgi to run.

In my case 5 processes in the .ini configuration file were to much to handle for my cpu this was my error output.

`your processes number limit is 3900
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024`

If this is your case lowering the number of processes to 2 in your .ini file might work.

Comment: Thank you, mine turned out to be a memory problem too. My app was on Google App Engine, but i couldn't find that particular error output in their daunting logging console!

Answer (score 1):

For me this problem was due to the users configuration. Basically, I set up all of my project using the root user. But then I redid everything from scratch using a non-root user with sudo privileges. It worked.

Comment: Do you recall why this was an issue exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I saw your comment on https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

try run `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start`
Then try open http://server_domain_or_IP

If it works, type `which uwsgi` to find the right uwsgi path and change "/etc/systemd/system/myproject.service"

change

`Environment="PATH=/home/sammy/myproject/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/sammy/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/uwsgi --ini myproject.ini`

into the real path instead of env path.

I figure out this problem through these command.

Comment: Good, But I dropped the idea of server setup, maybe in near future, it would be some help.

Answer (score 0):

As many people already mentioned, the 502 error is about socket permissions (you may see `Permission denied` errors in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`). However, it all seems to have to work, since

1. socket's  file ownership is `your_user:www-data`
2. socket's file permissions are 660 (which means that you and group can read/write socket)
3. nginx works with the user `www-data:www-data` (it's configured in nginx .conf file)

The real problem is that **nginx can't connect to the socket located in your home directory**!

So the solution is simple - just move the socket file somewhere else. For example, to `/tmp/` or `/var/www/...` folders.

---

**Solution:**

Create directories

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/your_project
sudo chown your_user:www-data /var/www/your_project
```

Modify `your_project.ini`

```
socket = /var/www/your_project/your_project.sock
```

Modify nginx server block

```
uwsgi_pass unix:///var/www/your_project/your_project.sock;
```

Restart uWSGI and nginx

```
sudo systemctl restart your_project_service
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

And it all has to work now.